# SQL multipart messages in two tables. Doesn't work if second table is empty

Tags: sql

I am working on a query that will fetch multipart messages from 2 tables. However, it only works IF there are multiple parts. If there is only a one part message then the the join condition won't be true anymore. How could I make it to work for both single and multipart messages?

Right now it fails if there is an entry in outbox and nothing in outbox_multipart.

My first table is "**outbox**" that looks like this.

```
TextDecoded  |  ID   |  CreatorID
Helllo, m..  |  123  |    Martin
Yes, I wi..  |  124  |    Martin
```

My second table is "**outbox_multipart**" that looks very similar.

```
TextDecoded  |  ID   |  SequencePosition
my name i..  |  123  |         2
s Martin.    |  123  |         3
ll do tha..  |  124  |         2
t tomorrow.  |  124  |         3
```

My query so far

```
SELECT 
  CONCAT(ob.TextDecoded, 
         GROUP_CONCAT(obm.TextDecoded 
                      ORDER BY obm.SequencePosition ASC 
                      SEPARATOR ''
                     )
        ) AS TextDecoded, 
  ob.ID, 
  ob.creatorID
FROM outbox AS ob 
JOIN outbox_multipart AS obm ON obm.ID = ob.ID 
GROUP BY 
  ob.ID, 
  ob.creatorID
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQLite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a left join instead of an (implicit) inner join.  Then, also use `COALESCE` on the `TextDecoded` alias to make sure that empty string (and not `NULL`) appears in the expected output.

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(ob.TextDecoded, 
           COALESCE(GROUP_CONCAT(obm.TextDecoded
                        ORDER BY obm.SequencePosition
                        SEPARATOR ''), '')) AS TextDecoded, 
    ob.ID,
    ob.creatorID
FROM outbox AS ob 
LEFT JOIN outbox_multipart AS obm
    ON obm.ID = ob.ID 
GROUP BY
    ob.ID,
    ob.creatorID,
    ob.TextDecoded;
```

Note: Strictly speaking, `outbox.TextDecoded` should also appear in the `GROUP BY` clause, since it is not an aggregate.  I have made this change in the query.

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect! Just a correction, you need to close all parentheses. ...SEPARATOR ''), '')) AS TextDecoded....